# Simple Mine-Sweeper using python. Mine in proximity function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to improve my code for finding mines in proximity in a mine-sweeper "game" on python.
It works, but I was wondering if there is anyway to improve it whilst still using dictionaries. 
I personally think the code could be better but can't really see how to do it better.
Thanks :D

```
grid = {}
grid[(0, 7)] = "Mine"
grid[(1, 5)] = "Mine"
grid[(1, 6)] = "Mine"
grid[(1, 8)] = "Mine"
grid[(2, 4)] = "Mine"
grid[(3, 4)] = "Mine"
grid[(5, 5)] = "Mine"
grid[(7, 0)] = "Mine"
grid[(7, 5)] = "Mine"


def mine_in_proximity(position, grid):
    death = False
    count = 0
    i, j = position[0], position[1]
    for n in range(i-1, i+2):
        for m in range(j-1, j+2):
            if (n, m) != (i, j):
                mine = grid.get((n, m), 0)
                if mine == "Mine":
                    count += 1
                elif mine == 0:
                    grid[position] = count
            else:
                deadly = grid.get((n, m), 0)
                if deadly == "Mine":
                    death = True
    return count, grid, death
```

Comment: Do you want `grid[position]` to be equal to the number of mines around it if it is not a mine itself? (on this line: `grid[position] = count`)

Comment: Yes, this is done so that a function that I am working on, Cell_Value, will print the value of the position in the dictionary, so when it is empty or non-existant, I print a blank space in the terminal

Comment: I think count will not be set properly. I believe it needs to be taken out of the loop that it is in or not in the elif. The way it is now, when the program is checking the last surrounding location for a mine, if it finds a mine it will increment count, but `grid[position]` will not be incremented

Comment: Thanks, had not seen that! ^^